# how do i set no value in @Html.AutoCompleteTextBoxFor in cshtml in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

how do i set no value in  `@Html.AutoCompleteTextBoxFor` in cshtml in **MVC**

In my partial view (i have used this as a popup)

```
@Html.AutoCompleteTextBoxFor(t => t.Name, t => t.SysId, new { @class = "textEntry" },
        new
            {
                src = "../../images/mytest.png",
                alt = "",
                onclick = "LoadData()"
            },
        new { type = "CustomerTestTable", propertyName = "Name" }, null)
```

But as i'm ``` binding value from Model it is showing ``Customer Name``. ```

How to achieve `null` (no value) instead `Model` name at first time when partial view load?

Comment: show your model please and how you init it in controller. Also, show your `AutoCompleteTextBoxFor` helper code. it's now standard helper.

Comment: model is nothing but a model class of `Customer` which load customer data.
 `var customer = //load values from customer.

return this.PartialView("PartialView", customer );`

Comment: but i don't get what do you mean by _first time load_? If you populate your model with delault values then your Helper shows this values. Don't you want to init new model? I mean `var customer = new Customer { Name = String.Empty }`

Comment: But actually i believe that it's your `AutoCompleteTextBoxFor` helper generates string `Customer Name`. Can you show it's code?

Comment: I tried with string and it works in all scenarios :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init your model with empty field, like this:

```
var customer = new Customer { Name = String.Empty }
```